# Can't access file with RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder Storage/static/css. And I want for design/css to see Storage/static/css content.

```
/Classes
    ...
...
/Storage
    /static
        /css
            /home
                design.css
            /menu
            /footer
        /js
            ...
    /uploads
        ...
...
index.php
```

I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^design/css/(.*)$ /Storage/static/css/$1

    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For index.php works fine for a long time ago.
But for the other one doesn't work at all.

I want for example:

For design/css/**home/design.css** to return content from Storage/static/css/**home/design.css**.

## Edit:

My entire web app isn't in root. It is inside a folder called /arshwell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally re-rewrite the css requests in a second go...

Have a try with this slightly modified version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?design/css/(.*)$ /Storage/static/css/$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [END]
```

This will prevent that requests rewritten to `/Storage/static/css/$1` will immediately get rewritten again to `index.php` by the next rule.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and in case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Hi. I do not have access to the real http servers host configuration.

Comment: Looks like the style sheets are not loaded. Could you please check in your browsers console what the request to the css file actually results in?

Comment: In Console Network, /design/css/... get a 403 and /Storage/static/css.. get a 403 (like in prnt.sc/md5oru).

Comment: Recursively, /Storage and all its folders has 0750 permissions and all its files has 0644 permissions.

Comment: 403 means target exists (so the rewriting most likely works correct), but access is forbidden. folder permission `0750`, hm, what user and what group do the folders belong, since the http server process needs to be able to enter them and access is explicitly denied for "others"?

Comment: /Storage and its whole content is created from php.

Comment: That alone does _not_ automatically mean that process can read those nodes again. It is likely, but you should check. Apart from that... you are aware of the security implications of allowing a web logic to alter it's own resources? An attacker can do anything to your site unless you implement a _perfect_ protection even against threads you did not imagine...

Comment: Anyway, next you will have to check for other configurations blocking those requests. How is access to that `/Storage` folder defined? What does the http servers host configuration say? Any _other_ dynamic configuration files (".htaccess")?

Comment: I create /Storage and its folders recursively with: mkdir("Storage/...", 0750, true);

Comment: I don't have access to host configuration because I use a host from a provider. So I only use FTP to access my web files.

Comment: This .htaccess (from root) is the only one.

Comment: Tricky with that little control you have over your things... Where is that folder located, physically, inside the file system? Inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`? How do you tell?

Comment: My entire web app (included /Storage) is in www.example.com/arshwell.

Comment: There has to be some factor denying access for those requests. It is not the rewriting, that _appears_ to work according to what you report. Something else is blocking. I cannot say what it is, you will have to contact your service provider and ask them...

Comment: Oh, one last shot, do you have access to the http server's error log file, or at least an excerpt from that?

Comment: I got an error_log file in my /arshwell folder when appeared php errors.

Comment: Nothing beside php internal errors in there? What are the last entries?

Comment: I just saw your edit to the question about the `arshwell` folder... Not sure what that means... Where is that `index.php` file located? Is _all_ the file tree you schetched inside that folder or not?

Comment: Yes. All the file tree I schetched is inside /arshwell folder. That is its name.

Comment: Hm, what happens if you change `RewriteRule ^design/css/(.*)$ /Storage/static/css/$1` to `RewriteRule ^design/css/(.*)$ Storage/static/css/$1` ?

Comment: I did it. Storage folder and its folders should be created, from php, with 0755.

Comment: Why that? Besides your own code this also depends on the ``umask`` set for the http server process which is outside your control if you are using a hosting provider. Any a umask denying access for "others" certainly does make sense on a shared system environment...

Comment: Yeah. But I use umask(0) php function which removes, temporary, restrictions on creating permissions.

Comment: Is, 0755 permissions on folders and 0644 permissions on files, unsecure?

Comment: You may use `umask(0)`, but you need to understand that this only removes the restrictions your own process implies. You _can not_ reset what your process received from that spwaning process. So if the system dictates you a more restrictive umask, then there is nothing you can do against that. Also this might be a file system restriction, the way the resource is mounted into the system.

Comment: Well, granting access to your files to _others_ does not really help you in any form, does it? And it certainly _might_ open security issues, since it actually allows processed owned by _others_ to access your files. Keep in mind that you share the system in a hosting environment by potentially thousands of other users. What if someone actively tries to access your files, is that really what you want to allow?

Comment: I understand. So which are the best/safe folder and file permissions ? Which also gives me freedom to do what I need, of course.

Comment: I think the current permissions are just fine, _if_ the user and group ownership of the folders allow the http server process to access / enter those folders. I asked about the ownership, you did not respond to that... But I actually doubt that is the issue.